# Large catalogs, to JSp page is causing OutOfMemoryErrors

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, out-of-memory

```
 Catalog catalogs= product.getAllCatalog();

 request.setAttribute("catalogs",catalogs); 
  ..
 ...
...
```

so when i am dispatching request to the JSP page with large no of catalogs size it  causing OutOfMemoryErrors .

can some one tell me how to fixed this problem ,any way to fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination can solve you problem .and in each iteration i.e when moving to next page clear your 1 level cache it can solve your problem .

For more infomation about how to implement pagination with example click [here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-handle-pagination-using-jsp-pages/28345)

Answer (score 1):

[Pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) is the way to go, don't load everything at once and load only required fields from `Catalog`

Answer (score 1):

try to use pagination or create a collection of beans that only hold the data that you really need

For example if you only display `field1`, `field2` and `field3` or your `Catalog` then create a bean with only these fields